# Update C++ variables from perl

Tags: c++, perl

I am fairly new to Perl and C++. I have a simple C++ code. I have to call its member functions and update its member variables from Perl.

I looked at several options but found them too confusing. Is there a way this can be done easily? 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you working on Linux or Windows? What options did you look at? Can you please explain the nature of these member functions? What sort of thing do they do?

Comment: Working on windows. Its a calculator class with add and subtract functions with two variables. A main function has a while(1) loop continuously calling either of these functions based on the value of the variables. I saw Inline::C and xsub

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that is simple and straightforward I'm afraid. From the nature of your application, it sounds like you are just experimenting with things, and it is probably not worth the work unless you are preparing for a more complex interface.

The standard way of calling C code from within Perl is to write XS code. It's documented in [`perldoc perlxs`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html). There is a specific section on [*Using XS With C++*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html#Using-XS-With-C%2b%2b) and a tutorial in [`perldoc perlxstut`](http://metacpan.org/module/perlxstut). But it sounds like you have already come across that and found it too confusing

If your code was built as a DLL then you could use [`Win32::API`](http://metacpan.org/module/Win32::API) to call the exported functions

Beyond that there isn't much I can suggest. If you explain your application, and why you are writing arithmetic functions in C++ then I'm sure we could suggest a better alternative

Comment: Yes I'm trying out how I can interface perl and C++ starting with the easy Calculator function. Based on this I can use similar approach for more complex C++ functions.

Comment: @user5485904: Okay then you want to learn about XS. There are several examples of it in modules on CPAN, and the tutorial that I linked above will get you started

Comment: Thank you. I'll refer to them :)